# What is HP contract toner with C suffix?

Tags: printing, hp-laserjet

HP offers many toner part numbers with a "C" suffix, e.g. for a LaserJet M5035 you can get two toner part numbers:

- Q7570A
- Q7570AC

The "C" suffix supposedly stands for "contract".

I've been unable to find any explanation of how these part numbers differ.

Comment: Did you try asking HP?

Comment: It's impossible to ask HP anything without paying money for it first, I'm afraid.

Comment: Call the sales department and tell them you want to buy some Q7570AC but you're not sure if that's the right part number.

Answer (score 2):

Both part numbers are identical products. The "C" suffix is added to parts available/sold through reseller channels. I've got confirmation from HP that the suffix does not indicate a part with decreased capacity.